# C# turn transparency into white for a .pdf document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, transparency, pdfnet

I have a .pdf document that has transparency in its pages.
I need to remove that transparency and make it white, how can I do that with C#?
I can use pdftron, itextsharp or any other free library.

Comment: The idea is to supply draw a white rectangle underneath the whole page. Thus, wherever there was transparency there now is that white rectangle. One merely might have to consider the knockout setting... beware: this of course does not miraculously cause printers to spray white ink there...

Answer (score 0):

Using PDFTrons PDFNet SDK, you can insert a white rectangle as the background to remove the default page transparency as suggested by @mkl. Below is an example using the [ElementBuilder](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/html/T_pdftron_PDF_ElementBuilder.htm) class. You can look at the [ElementBuilder sample code](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode/ElementBuilderTest.cs.html) for more information.

```
using (PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(@"D:\in.pdf"))
using (ElementBuilder eb = new ElementBuilder())
using (ElementWriter writer = new ElementWriter())
{
    int pagenum = 1;
    writer.Begin(doc.GetPage(pagenum), ElementWriter.WriteMode.e_underlay);
    Element e = eb.CreateRect(0, 0, doc.GetPage(pagenum).GetPageWidth(), doc.GetPage(pagenum).GetPageHeight());
    e.SetPathFill(true);
    e.SetPathStroke(true);
    e.SetPathClip(false);
    e.GetGState().SetFillColorSpace(ColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB());
    e.GetGState().SetStrokeColorSpace(ColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB());
    e.GetGState().SetStrokeColor(new ColorPt(255, 255, 255)); // white background fill color 
    e.GetGState().SetFillColor(new ColorPt(255, 255, 255)); // stroke color white as well
    writer.WritePlacedElement(e);
    writer.End();

    doc.Save(@"D:\output.pdf", 0);
}
```